# My HTML document find a div but actually no div tag have written

Tags: html, css

The following is simple HTML and CSS.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="CSS/Smile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    this is a test
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body
{
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}
div
{
  border:1px solid green;
}
```

When I preview the page in a browser, I see a green border underneath the text. Here's an image of what I see:

[image]

**Question**

What's going on there?

Comment: Are you using any frameworks/Plugins..? it might be injecting divs. also, which browser, what version..? can you reproduce this ..?

Comment: any fiddle? looks like your HTML code or CSS has some error

Comment: are you sure it's not cached, because you previously used a div? refresh with ctrl+ f5 or select disable cache in developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, I think the page is cached. Here's a helper to test your html, css, etc code in future. http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct is , you write in your body of html,

```
 HTML:
   <body>
        this is a test
   </body>
```

so the text you write is shown in the browser, more you  also use

```
 CSS:
 border:1px solid green;
```

So  solid green border is showing in your browser,if you use red, then it will be red color border.
Hope you it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The green border doesn't come with your code. I tried the same code at jsfiddle and there is no green border (try jsfiddle.net/jere123/qc7qT/ ) ;)

So what you have to do:

1. Try to clear your **cache**..
2. Rightclick on the green border and go to "**inspect element**". That shows you what part of the code produces the green line. If you dont know how to handle with the information of the inspector write them down in an update of your question.